# Is every countable space first countable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

All of the examples of non-first countable spaces I have seen are uncountable (for instance any uncountable set with the cofinite topology). I would like to know if every countably infinite $T_1$ space $X$ is first countable. Since $\{A\subseteq X|x\in A\}$ for a given $x\in X$ is uncountable, there doesn't seem to be a 1-line proof; a proof should require use of the axioms of a topology.

Perhaps I haven't seen a proof or counterexample anywhere because I haven't looked in the right place or am simply missing an "obvious" proof or counterexample. Maybe someone can point me to a reference or exercise in a textbook where this shows up.

Comment: The best place to look for things like this is Steen and Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look up [Arens-Fort space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space).

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

(What follows is adapted from a couple of old sci.math posts of mine, from 2001 and 2008. URLs below if anyone is interested.)

It is possible for countable space, even a countable regular Hausdorff space, to not be first countable. The key in making this happen is that although each subset of a countable space must be countable, a *collection of subsets* of a countable space can be uncountable. In fact, there even exist countable (regular Hausdorff) spaces that have **no points of first countability**, where $x \in X$ *is a point of first countability of the topological space* $X$ means that every neighborhood of $x$ (when viewed as a topological space with the subspace topology inherited from $X$) fails to be first countable.  For some examples, see:

Peter Wamer Harley, *A countable nowhere first countable Hausdorff space*, Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 16 (1973), 441-442.

http://tinyurl.com/5bdddb  [.pdf file of Harley's paper]

Ronald [Ronnie] Fred Levy, *Countable spaces without points of first countability*, Pacific Journal of Mathematics 70 (1977), 391-399. [Proposition 2.1 gives $2^c$ many pairwise non-homeomorphic countable regular Hausdorff spaces, each of which has no points of first countability.]

http://tinyurl.com/6f9u24  [.pdf file of Levy's paper]

Richard Curtis Willmott, *Countable yet nowhere first countable*, Mathematics Magazine 52 (1979), 26-27.

Besides Levy, Leslie Owen Foged also constructed $2^c$ nonhomeomorphic countable spaces having no points of first countability in his 1979 Ph.D. Dissertation (under Ron Freiwald, Washington University) **Weak Bases for Topological Spaces**. I believe the spaces Foged constructed were also Hausdorff and regular, but I'm not certain about this.

http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/0b0494e83cbf472c

http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/dae28a80411cf603

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am curious to know if any of these countable, nowhere first countable spaces are homogeneous.

Comment: I see. Yes, Levy's examples are homogeneous.

Comment: @J.T.: The $2^c$ many examples Levy gives are all homogeneous, but I don't know about the others. After submitting this I saw your second comment, but don't know how to delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Other interesting counterexamples:

> [Appert Space](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [Maximal Compact Topology](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [One Point Compactification fo the Rationals](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)
>
> [Single Ultrafilter Topology](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146)